# Degree of intersection of splitting fields $|K\cap L:\mathbb{Q}|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I've been working on some exercises on Galois theory and I'm a little stuck in one of them: Let $L$ be the splitting field of the polynomial $x^3-10$ (so $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{10},\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is complex cubic root of unity) and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-7})$. I need to compute the degree of $K\cap L$, $|K\cap L:\mathbb{Q}|$. I computed the degrees of $K$ and $L$ and they are $4$ and $6$ respectively, so $|K\cap L:\mathbb{Q}|$ must be $1$ or $2$. It probably is $1$ but I can't find any good reason, so I need some hints.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

If $[K \cap L : \mathbb{Q}]=2$, then $K$ and $L$ share a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Now $L$ only has one quadratic subfield whereas $K$ has three - can you work out what these subfields are explicitly (ie write them uniquely as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ with $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ squarefree)?

Comment: The quadratic extensions of $K$ are $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for $d=5,-7$ and $-35$, while that of $L$ is for $d=10$. Am I right? If that is the case I only have to show that these are the only ones and the result will immediately follow, right?

Comment: You are right for $K$ but $\sqrt{10} \not\in L$ so you need to rethink that one. Also, if you know any Galois theory, then this will help prove that these are the only ones and then yes the result will follow as two quadratic fields in this form are equal if and only if the corresponding $d$'s are.